# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null / on tensorflowjs prediction

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I face the problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null on prediction using tensorflowjs(tfjs) .

I checked 'batched' is right array as input of dnn model.

The code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="cat_leaf" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/test_data/test03.JPG" width=256 height=256 alt="My Image" />
<input type = "button" value = "Image GOGO!" onclick= "img_pred()"  />
<script>
async function img_pred(){
    const catElement = document.getElementById("cat_leaf");    
    const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(catElement).toFloat();    
    const offset = tf.scalar(225.0);
    // Normalize the image from 
    const normalized = img.div(offset);    
    // Reshape to a single-element batch so we can pass it to predict.
    const batched = normalized.reshape([1, 256, 256, 3]);    
    //console.log('batched1',batched.toString())
    const gt_mode = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/tea_model02/model.json');
    const gopred =gt_mode.predict(batched);  //occurred error here!!
    const y_pred__ =  gopred.toString() ;   
    console.log('result**',y_pred__);
    //return gt_mode.predict(batched);
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the function `gt_mode.predict`

Comment: gt_mode is my dnn model and predict is tfjs function. so, gt_mode.predict() is prediction using trained model.

Comment: so, it's code in there that is the problem according to you ... so, how are we supposed to know what you're doing in your function?